# Is there a way to assign a title to a Constructed Stylesheet so that the given title appears next to rules from it in the Chrome Inspector?

Tags: css, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-devtools, web-component

I've been using Constructable Stylesheets for web components. Thus far I've been frontloading them all into a singleton and mass sharing them across the Document and every component's ShadowRoot. This works well behavior-wise, and I have URLs and names associated with each stylesheet in my singleton; however, when viewing the rules affecting an element in the Google Chrome inspector, all it says for the source is "constructed stylesheet". If possible, I'd like to know how I can configure the `CSSStyleSheet` instances so that the source text more accurately conveys from which file or CSSStyleSheet instance the rule is originating.

When examining the MDN documentation for [StyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet) and [CSSStyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet), the only instance properties that seemed to provide identifying information were `href` and `title`, both of which are read-only properties from the base class with no apparent way of setting them from the `CSSStyleSheet` constructor.

Is there something I'm missing?

Edit: I am aware of [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76143524/can-a-unique-identifier-be-applied-to-a-constructable-stylesheet) that wishes to know how to uniquely inject Constructable StyleSheets, but my singleton already fulfills the answer there. That question does nothing to actually resolve the problem of associating a particular Constructable StyleSheet instance with information rendered in the browser dev tools.

Comment: I have never been able to figure out exactly what the 'title' property is used for. its a configurable property, so even though its not directly writable, you can over-write it with a call to Object.defineProperty - but doing that seems to have no affect on anything other than what is shown in the inspector when looking at it. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯  I don't believe you are missing anything, i think this is just the unfortunate reality of working with a newish api that doesn't seem to get much attention.

Comment: Try suggesting it in W3C. BTW the inline `<style>` elements can use sourceURL comments `/*# sourceURL=foo://bar/file.css */` that are shown in devtools so adding an identifier to this API (e.g. as a CSSStyleSheet parameter) or the ability to retain sourceURL comment would make sense.

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm. I have gone ahead and created a [GitHub issue requesting a solution to this problem](https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/1024).